# Hide empty line if the content after <br> is empty

Tags: php

I want to show the alternative names of a place. Separate variables will contain each alternative names taken from custom fields. But, some variables will have an empty value.

```
<?php
    $alt-name1 = "A"
    $alt-name2 = "B"
    $alt-name3 = ""
    $alt-name4 = "D"
    $alt-name5 = ""

printf('%s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s', $alt-name1, $alt-name2, $alt-name3, $alt-name4, $alt-name5);
?>
```

This shows as:

A

B


D

**How can I hide the empty spaces in the output so it shows like this?:**

A

B

D

I've tried this in CSS:

```
br:empty {display: none;}
```

But, it hides all the `<br>` and gives the output as: ABD

**Note:** I have an alternative plan to execute this by concatenating `<br>` with the variables like this:

```
<?php
    $alt-name1 = "A"
    $alt-name2 = "B"
    $alt-name3 = ""
    $alt-name4 = "D"
    $alt-name5 = ""

    if($alt-name2 != "") {$alt-name2 = "<br>".$alt-name2;}
    if($alt-name3 != "") {$alt-name3 = "<br>".$alt-name3;}
    if($alt-name4 != "") {$alt-name4 = "<br>".$alt-name4;}
    if($alt-name5 != "") {$alt-name5 = "<br>".$alt-name5;}

printf('%s%s%s%s%s', $alt-name1, $alt-name2, $alt-name3, $alt-name4, $alt-name5);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the values you don't want are equivalent to Boolean false (empty strings convert to false). So, you can get all non-empty values using:

```
array_filter($alt);
```

That requires the values to be in an array. I assume they are in an array before you converted them to a bunch of independent variables, but you could do:

```
$alt = array($alt-name1, $alt-name2, $alt-name3);
```

I hope you know that $alt-name1 is not a valid variable name. I'm using it because you used it in your question. To reiterate, put your values in an array.

The addition of <br> between each value is a good task for implode. It places whatever you want between each element of an array. So, you can use:

```
implode("<br>", $alt);
```

Putting this all together, assuming $alt is your array of all the values you want to print, you can use:

```
print implode("<br>", array_filter($alt));
```

This will not add a <br> after the last item in the array, which I prefer. You can print "<br>" after it if you want the extra tag.

--UPDATE--

Based on the comment below, there is a completely new requirement to print "Not Available" if all elements of $alt are empty. Again, array_filter helps. If all elements are empty, it will return an empty array. An empty array converts to Boolean false. So, you can use:

```
if(!array_filter($alt)) print "Not Available";
else print implode("<br>",array_filter($alt));
```

Comment: Thank you @kainaw.
However, my plan is to show a string "Not Available" if all alternative names are empty. In this case, can I use this condition?


`if(array_filter($alt) == "") {$alt = "Not available";}`